# Convergence of ${a_n}$ = $\sum _1^n \frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does the series ${a_n}$ = $\sum _1^n \frac{1}{n^{1+\alpha}}$ converge for all $\alpha$ > 0?

Comment: Are you wanting a *sequence* $a_n$ or a *series* $\sum a_n$?

Comment: I think he meant partial sum $a_n$

Comment: I meant the partial sum

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use the [Integral Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence).

Comment: can you give more information on Integral test?

Comment: I’ve added a link to the Wikipedia article on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{k}}$ converges for all $k>1$. It is divergent if $k \le 1$. It is a generalization of the [Harmonic Series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series).